# Running Python 3.7 and Selenium: How do I reply to the Firefox Password Manager Popup when running a script?

Tags: python, selenium, firefox

I am grinding through day 2 of me learning Python 3.7 with Selenium.

I am accessing a web page using WebDriver. I have been making progress, but am stymied now. Though I can easily disable the Firefox password manager popup window on my normal Browser (Options/Privacy and Security/Location/Settings), my script's remotely-run (think that is by definition) browser does not recognize that configuration, and the Firefox popup shows up.

The script can ignore the popup and navigate the target site until the very last page that I need to access. At that point, the HTML for that page is inaccessible, until I manually click on the Firefox popup, dismissing it. As soon as I do that, the HTML code for that web page lights up in Firefox Web Developer Inspector.

Now, that HTML code may be inaccessible for other reasons (like I said, day 2 of the learning curve), but is there some library or commands within Webdriver that allow me to automate the dismissal of that FireFox popup. It is not part of the HTML of any page, so I am at a loss.

Edit: I should mention also, the bulk of that last page's content is blank until I manually dismiss the FireFox popup.

I have added the following code, but still am getting the same popup:

```
from selenium import webdriver

#Using Firefox to access the Web
options = webdriver.FirefoxOptions()
options.set_preference("dom.webnotifications.enabled", False)
driver = webdriver.Firefox(options=options)
driver.maximize_window()
```

Second Edit: This is the current code section defining the profile, and I am still getting the pop up password manager.

```
import datetime
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

#Using Firefox to access the Web
profile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()

#profile.set_preference("dom.push.enabled", False)
profile.set_preference("dom.webnotifications.enabled", False)
profile.update_preferences()
driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_profile=profile)
driver.maximize_window()
```

Comment: Did you set your Selenium to use a certain firefox profile?

Comment: I did not. I read in another comment that Firefox profiles are deprecated. How do I set a profile?

Comment: I have added my 2nd edit in the original post, which shows the code that pertains to the profile. I am still seeing the pop up password manager.

Answer (score 0):

0. about:config
1. preference security.insecure_field_warning.contextual.enabled to false

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).